# Which part of Id token i can used to identify one domain

Tags: outlook, office-js, office-addins

The document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/inside-the-identity-token, it introduces the content in the outlook AddIn id token, and i found there are two different keys "ISS" and "APPCTXSender", i want to know what's the different usage between them. Also I want to know which part of them i can used to identity one domain/org/tenant.

Comment: welcome to SO ! please edit the question instead of adding a new one in the comment section.

Answer (score 0):

To uniquely identify a user via identity token, we recommend that you combine the `msexchuid` and `amurl` properties in the response (see "Generating a unique ID"
 on [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/authenticate-a-user-with-an-identity-token).) As for the other half of your question, could you tell us more about your scenario and why you are looking for tenant/domain?